# Error while parsing XSL file

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, xslt, xml-parsing, ibm-rad

I am migrating and old web application from **Tomcat 4.0** to **WAS 6.1**.

We use a lot of **xslt transformations** like this (simplificated):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      version="1.0"
      xmlns:java="com.map.agro.Util">

      <xsl:variable name="LAWEBAPP">
            <xsl:value-of select="java:getCtx('BACK')"/>
      </xsl:variable>


<xsl:template match="ROW">
<a><xsl:attribute name="href">/<xsl:value-of select="$LAWEBAPP"/>/search.jsp</a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works in Tomcat 4.0, but not in WAS 6.1, where it complains with:

```
XSL-1000: (Fatal Error) Error while parsing XSL file (Extension function namespace should start with 'http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/'.).
```

I've tried several variations found in Google without success.

Does somebody know what could be happening here and how to solve it?

(What is the .jar library responsible of that xslt transformations?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,

In the classpath, there was a library called **xmlparserv2.jar**, with a "problematic" xslt processor (under **javax.xml.transform** basis).

**Removing** it from the project, do the thing.

Now, other library does the xslt transformation (under **org.apache.xalan.xslt** basis).

This post helped me a lot: 
[What processor is javax.xml.transform Using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647097/what-processor-is-javax-xml-transform-using)